# How to create DetailTemplate with static json datasource in KendoUI Grid to prevent ajax requests

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I would like to create static ClientTemplates for each row of the master grid. The master grid has a read.Action as datasource but the ClientTemplates should be already loaded without another request. 
It is possible to use a foreach loop to create the ClientTemplates server-side like

```
<script id="detailTemplate_1" type="text/x-kendo-template">         
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()...

<script id="detailTemplate_2" type="text/x-kendo-template">              
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()...
```

The datasource should be a json string so I don't need another request.

The master grid should looks like

```
.ClientDetailTemplateId("detailTemplate_#=id#")...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load the data for all detail rows (and possible the main grid, if you want to cut down on total requests and can do without server-side paging etc) in an ajax request before creating the grid, then use the [`detailInit`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-detailInit) event ([builder for MVC](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridEventBuilder#methods-DetailInit%28System.String%29)) to create the detail row content from that. I'm not sure whether this is possible using the MVC wrappers only.